# Items in a inline list are not aligning

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I have been trying to get social media links to work inline. I'm adding in the embed code that tripadvisor gave me. When the page loads the tripadvisor link will start on the bottom side of the nav bar and then once the page has loaded it will move to about 5px above where it should be.

I made a js fiddle to illustrate what is happening:

```
<ul class="list-inline">
    <li>
        <div id="TA_socialButtonReviews926" class="TA_socialButtonReviews">
            <ul id="6oLG9rtu" class="TA_links HjEmbbr2fxOd">
                <li id="SW60z8" class="tZqr47d8">
                    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.tripadvisor.com.au/Hotel_Review-g255060-d256527-Reviews-The_Menzies_Sydney-Sydney_New_South_Wales.html"><img src="http://www.tripadvisor.com.au/img/cdsi/img2/branding/socialWidget/20x28_green-21692-2.png"/></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script src="http://www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=socialButtonReviews&amp;uniq=926&amp;locationId=256527&amp;color=green&amp;size=rect&amp;lang=en_AU&amp;display_version=2"></script>
    </li>
    <li>
        <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fgeekdotcom&amp;width&amp;layout=button_count&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=false&amp;height=21&amp;appId=216772831136" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
    </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z2mz4ry9/

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A simple float did the trick:

```
li {
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/2rrrs31f/

Comment: Hello that seemed to work, i floated the li for tripadvisor which was out of place and now there all in line. One more question but i wanted to have all the social media links centered. If i text-align:center on the ul all the element go to the center other then the one which i had to float to the left. I tried to float: center, but that didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try floating both of the `li`s: https://jsfiddle.net/rgausnet/2uh34s0j/1/

Answer (score 0):

This might be sloppy, but adding `style="position:relative;top:5px;"` into `id="TA_socialButtonReviews926"` seems to do the trick.